# How to query between Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, between

I am querying a table with a time column returned in the format below:

```
2020-12-30 18:26:23.537
2020-12-30 17:43:19.707
2020-12-30 15:36:13.653
2020-12-30 15:35:23.160
2020-12-30 15:23:33.063
2020-12-30 15:22:42.243
2020-12-30 15:18:26.230
2020-12-30 15:15:20.083
2020-12-30 15:13:08.813
```

When I query what format this column is it shows as datetime. Update:
Using this query it returns date time:
`SELECT DATA_TYPE  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'vStatusMessagesWithStrings' AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'TIme'`

I have tried to narrow down results through a where statement in many ways but every time I run it I just get what looks like all the dates returned, all the way back to July.

I have tried just using `>= and <=` and I have also tried use "Between" but nothing works.
I have tried with just the string as `20201228` as `2020-12-28` and as `2020/12/30` but does not help.
I read that when using between you need to specify the time as well so I have tried it down to the millisecond but still returns everything. I have tried cast and convert on the date strings and nothing works.

here are a few examples of the different formats I have tried in my where statement:

```
and (sms.[Time] <= (convert(date,'20201228')) and SMS.[TIME] >= (convert(date,'20201222')))
and (sms.[Time] >= '20201222' and  SMS.[Time] <= '20201228')
and ((sms.[Time] >= Cast('20201222' as DateTime)) and  (SMS.[Time] <= Cast('20201228' as DateTime)))
and (sms.[Time] Between Cast('20201222 00:00:00.000' as DateTime) and  Cast('20201228 00:00:00.000' as DateTime))
and (sms.[Time] Between Cast('2020-12-22 00:00:00.000' as DateTime) and  Cast('2020-12-28 00:00:00.000' as DateTime))
and ((sms.[Time] >= Cast('2020-12-22 00:00:00.000' as DateTime)) and sms.[Time] <= Cast('2020-12-28 00:00:00.000' as DateTime))
and ((sms.[Time] >= '2020-12-22' ) and (sms.[Time] <= '2020-12-28'))
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  Your example mostly look reasonable.

Comment: What goes before the `and`? Is there an `or` in the `where` clause

Comment: ^^^^ Thats the actual answer :) well spotted

Comment: Glad you got it. Next time post the **whole** code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else going on because every example you say you tried works for me e.g.

```
declare @Test table ([time] datetime);

insert into @Test ([Time])
values
('2020-12-21T18:26:23.537'),
('2020-12-22T17:43:19.707'),
('2020-12-23T15:36:13.653'),
('2020-12-24T15:35:23.160'),
('2020-12-25T15:23:33.063'),
('2020-12-26T15:22:42.243'),
('2020-12-27T15:18:26.230'),
('2020-12-28T15:15:20.083'),
('2020-12-29T15:13:08.813');

select *
from @Test sms
where sms.[Time] between cast('2020-12-22T00:00:00.000' as datetime) and cast('2020-12-28T00:00:00.000' as datetime);
```

Returns:

| time |
| --- |
| 2020-12-22 17:43:19.707 |
| 2020-12-23 15:36:13.653 |
| 2020-12-24 15:35:23.160 |
| 2020-12-25 15:23:33.063 |
| 2020-12-26 15:22:42.243 |
| 2020-12-27 15:18:26.230 |

Note, you need to be careful using [`between`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) because it works as `>=` first limit and `<=` second limit, which can produce unexpected results. Especially in situations like this were you have a time component.

Personally I always use the following pattern to be sure I get the exact dates I am asking for:

```
select *
from @Test sms
where sms.[Time] >= cast('2020-12-22T00:00:00.000' as datetime) and sms.[Time] < dateadd(day, 1, cast('2020-12-28T00:00:00.000' as datetime));
```

Returns:

| time |
| --- |
| 2020-12-22 17:43:19.707 |
| 2020-12-23 15:36:13.653 |
| 2020-12-24 15:35:23.160 |
| 2020-12-25 15:23:33.063 |
| 2020-12-26 15:22:42.243 |
| 2020-12-27 15:18:26.230 |
| 2020-12-28 15:15:20.083 |

You'll notice that now includes the 28th whereas the previous query didn't.

Comment: I would personally recommend using `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnn` if you are using a `datetime`. If you're not American, SQL Server makes some odd choices on what the value means.

Comment: @DaleK I tried what you showed after inserting some of the dates i pulled from my query results and yes it does work.  What could be going on?  If it is in utc time would that make a difference?  Do I need convert the column first or something?

Comment: i used this query to check what data type the column is. I added it to the original post too `SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'vStatusMessagesWithStrings' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'TIme'`

`DATA_TYPE
datetime`

Comment:  Youre right, im drunk. I over looked my or statement above that.  I Put that in parenthesis and now get the correct range.

Comment: Thanks @Dalek, i didnt add the whole query because of how long it was with my case statements, but i guess i could have just removed those.